# StringTranslate() function in Python

Tags: python, string

In VFP there is a common function in most languages.  It is: `STRTRAN(var1,'abc')` 
This function adjusts the var1 variable by taking out the sub-string "abc".

As an example:

`STRTRAN("Hello yee valiant ones!", 'yee ')` leads to `"Hello valiant ones!"`

Does python have anything like that?  I only find some RegEx and confounding ways which is rather abstruse to me.

Many thanx for your help

DK

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `str.replace`:

```
>>> strs = "Hello yee valiant ones!"
>>> strs.replace(' yee','')
'Hello valiant ones!'
#or
>>> strs.replace('yee ','')
'Hello valiant ones!'
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a `str.translate` method but it only works for isolated characters. You probably want `str.replace`:

```
>>> "Hello yee valiant ones!".replace('yee ', '')
'Hello valiant ones!'
```